# No .gitignore template for javascript when using "gh repo" command? (Github CLI)

Tags: javascript, typescript, github, gitignore, github-cli

I'm trying to use Github's Command Line Interface to create a new web project.

When I use the `gh repo` command to create a new repo, why is there no option for a `Javascript` or `Typescript` .gitignore template?

What kind of .gitignore do you recommend for a javascript or typescript project when setting up a git repository this way?

[Choose a .gitignore template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xfg9.png)

I tired scrolling through the options for .gitignore templates, including looking next to the `Java`, and `Typo3` terms. I expected there to be a Javascript or Typescript option.

Comment: I'm sure there will template named with `Node`. try it.